# Blank border when importing eps files

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, borders, eps

I'm really new using illustrator (to be honnest, it's only been two days). 
When I try to open eps files, there is a big blank border appearing around the image I've opened. I really don't know if it's normal but is there a way to open them without that blank page behind my image ?

I thought it would be fine when saving (in .svg format) but no, the svg file contains these borders.

My final aim is to create a script to convert eps files into svg because I've a lot of them to convert.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot after importing the image? Also, please, try to press Object->Artboards->Fit to artwork bounds

Comment: I can't show you the image for many reasons but "fit to artwork bounds" is working perfectly. Is there a way to do it with a script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you describe is related to the difference in the image size you open and artboard size of a newly created document.

To fit these two you can fit the artboard to image size by pressing

Object->Artboards->Fit to Artwork Bounds.

This task can be easily scripted, just start learning...